# Checking if a date is in between other dates in php not behaving as it should

Tags: php, date

I've been searching for how to check if a date is inbetween other dates and it appears from what I've read that I can just use an if statement with the date() function in php

The function I've made works in most cases, but sometimes it's wrong. I'm not sure why.

```
function checkToday($date1, $date2, $today)
{

    if($date1 < $today && $date2 > $today )
    {
        return "between";
    } elseif ($date1 < $today) {
        return "before";
    } else {
        return "after";
    }
}
```

I've called it with many different dates and they all appear to work except for this one:

```
$startDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("07-03-2016"));
$endDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("19-05-2016"));
$currDate= date('d-m-Y');
$check = checkToday($startDate, $endDate, $currDate);
echo $check.' ';
echo $startDate.' ';
echo $endDate.' ';
echo $currDate.' ';
```

This outputs: before 07-03-2016 19-05-2016 22-04-2016

But, clearly 22-04-2016 is in between 07-03-2016 and 19-05-2016

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: compare timestaps but not srings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the dates as strings, that's why it doesn't work properly.

You need to compare the timestamps (returned by [`time()`](http://php.net/time) or [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)) or use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) objects.

**Example with DateTime :**

```
<?php

function checkToday($date1, $date2, $today)
{    
    if( $date1 < $today && $date2 > $today )
    {
        return "between";
    } elseif ($date1 < $today) {
        return "before";
    } else {
        return "after";
    }
}

$startDate = new DateTime("2016-03-07");
$endDate = new DateTime("2016-05-19");
$currDate= new DateTime();
$check = checkToday($startDate, $endDate, $currDate);

echo $check.' '; // Returns between
echo $startDate->format("d-m-Y").' ';
echo $endDate->format("d-m-Y").' ';
echo $currDate->format("d-m-Y").' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in php. You should use this function to compare dates in php as like below

```
function checkToday($date1, $date2, $today)
{    
    if( strtotime($date1) < strtotime($today) && strtotime($date2) > strtotime($today) )
    {
        return "between";
    } elseif ( strtotime($date1) < strtotime($today) ) {
        return "before";
    } else {
        return "after";
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it must be something simple! Thank you so much. This fixed it

Comment: I don't have enough 'Reputation' to do so yet. It won't show publicly.